# Unable to persist the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am unable to persist the check boxes when i have changed  the component and came return back...just i want to persist the checked check box

this is the link of codesand box : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-glitter-0or0t?file=/src/components/branches.js...please see above link in code sand box...

courses.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

// const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);
class CheckboxComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: {},
      count: 0,
      checked: true
    };
    this.ChangeCheckBox = this.ChangeCheckBox.bind(this);
    this.checkBoxSubmit = this.checkBoxSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  ChangeCheckBox = e => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    let { count } = this.state;
    let value = this.state.values;
    if (checked) {
      // console.log("checked");
      count++;
      this.setState({
        checked
      });
    } else {
      // console.log("un-checked");
      count--;
    }
    this.setState({ count });
    // console.log(count);
    // console.log(checked);
    // console.log(value);

    value[e.target.value] = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ values: value });
  };
  checkBoxSubmit = e => {
    let CheckedValues = this.state.values;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(CheckedValues);
  };
  render() {
    const arr = ["Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.checkBoxSubmit}>
          <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
            <List className="courses-college-regis">
              {arr.map((a, key) => (
                <ListItem button key={key}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    label={a}
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={a}
                    name={a}
                    control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                    onChange={this.ChangeCheckBox}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </FormGroup>
          count:{this.state.count}
          <br />
          <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```

branch.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

// const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);
class BranchComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: {},
      count: 0,
      checked: true
    };
    this.ChangeCheckBox = this.ChangeCheckBox.bind(this);
    this.checkBoxSubmit = this.checkBoxSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  ChangeCheckBox = e => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    let { count } = this.state;
    let value = this.state.values;
    if (checked) {
      // console.log("checked");
      count++;
      this.setState({
        checked
      })
    } else {
      // console.log("un-checked");
      count--;
    }
    this.setState({ count });
    // console.log(count);
    // console.log(checked);
    // console.log(value);

    value[e.target.value] = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ values: value });
  };
  checkBoxSubmit = e => {
    let CheckedValues = this.state.values;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(CheckedValues);
    localStorage.setItem('this.state.values', CheckedValues)
  };
  render() {
    const arr = ["Branch 1", "Branch 2", "Branch 3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <form onSubmit={this.checkBoxSubmit}>
          <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
            <List className="courses-college-regis">
              {arr.map((a, key) => (
                <ListItem button key={key}>
                  <FormControlLabel
                    label={a}
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={a}
                    name={a}
                    control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                    onChange={this.ChangeCheckBox}
                  />
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
          </FormGroup>
          count:{this.state.count}
          <br />
          <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default BranchComponent;
```

Comment: What do you mean by persist the checkboxes? Do you mean within a single page load or across page loads? If the latter, you'll need a server with a database and some endpoints or at least local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save those to values to `localStorage`.

Change your initial `state` to this:

```
this.state = {
   values: {},
   count: 0,
   checked: localStorage.getItem('checkbox') === 'true' ? true : false
};
```

And then in your `ChangeCheckBox` handler, add this line at the bottom of it:

```
localStorage.setItem('checkbox', e.target.checked.toString())
```

This updates the value at the `localStorage` key that you provide and then sets your initial state to that key value that is saved in local storage.

Comment: its not working Barry....if i change the tried to change component..came came...check is disappearing

Comment: You need to make your checkbox controlled, so the `checked` value on your form control should be set to `this.state.checked`.

Comment: if i do like that....check boxes are not working properly...https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shadow-6fmv0?file=/src/components/branches.js

Comment: Well you need to keep the array in state and persist that and keep their checked values in there.

Comment: Look your question was about how to use persist state, I gave you a solution to persist state keys. You need to change the app yourself first to make sure that you checkbox values are controlled and linked to state.  Once you've done that, I'll update my answer to fix the problem. I'm not writing your app for you.